# How to transfer a hex file from android app to Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) module?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm developing an android app to transfer a hex file over BLE to a BLE module.
I have established the connection between the app and the BLE module using [BluetoothGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt) class. Now I want to send the hex file. Then the BLE module will receive the file and write to an SD card connected to that module.

Answer (score 0):

Balaraman.

Using  BluetoothGatt you can write to particular service and be notified about the result from that service. like explained in this link.

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-communicate-with-a-custom-ble-using-an-android-app/

if you want to write hex commands to receive data from bluetooth device by notify or read, you can follow above tutorial.

But if HEX file contains some commands for the BLE module(Device) to make sure the BLE device updated by new code in the device itself, you need to flash those on to the device by the micro controller within it.

I don't know how but in my former work place our Hardware engineer used to do that, whenever there was need to update the device code..